# put a button in the *NgFor for each row

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a website as shown in the picture. I created the list with *NgFor. I want to put the favorite button on each line. I want to add the information of that line to the favorites by pressing the favorite button

[website home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD6DB.png)

my *ngfor loop. just i want button for each "favori columns"

```html
    <table id="news">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of headers">
                {{col}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    
        <tr *ngFor="let new of news">
            <td *ngFor="let col of index">
                {{new[col]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

After creating the button, I will connect with mongo myself

Comment: this important for me! please help

Comment: just render button inside of tag with *ngFor ` <td *ngFor="let col of index">
            <button>click me</button>        </td>`

Comment: how can i get the information of each line basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a button in ngFor like so:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let new of news">
    <td *ngFor="let col of index">      
       {{ new[col] }}
    </td>
    <td>
       <button>Favorite</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how can i get the information of each line basically

Comment: If by 'line' you mean 'row', you can see that it <tr> you loop through news. Inside that loop, you have another loop <td>, where you show every property of each 'new', and at the and you add a button, in the last <td>. If you need to access to some information of the 'new', you can easily write something like {{new.property}}.
And if you need to send lets say an id of 'new' to some method triggered by click, then you do something like this: <button (click)="someMethod(new[id])">Favorite</button>

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let new of news>
<td *ngFor="let col of index>
   {{new[col]}}
</td>
<td>
       <button>col.propertyname</button>
    </td>
</table>
```

thanks

Comment: The requirement is to put a button on each line, not in header. Besides, it is a HTML table, not a list

Comment: i just give you an example you can modify that my previous answer and i just modify it.